# REST: One to Many for GET via a foreign key

Tags: api, rest

**Relationships**

- `robot` has many `brains`
- `brain` has one `robot`

**Background**

How to form the resource URL where we provide a `robotId` (foreign key) to retrieve its `brain`?

I could come up with this resource:
`GET /robots/:robotId/brain`

I am not sure if using `brain` in singular is against REST conventions and practices. 
However, using `GET /robots/:robotId/brains` (brain in plurals) implies a collection will be returned but it will always have 1 item only.

**Question**

Can you advise me on a RESTful way?

Comment: If your endpoint retrieves a robot won't that also get the brain(s) associated with the robot ?

Comment: @auburg Nope, it will not. I used some model resources. A `brain` is identified via a foreign key `robotId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you advise me on a RESTful way?

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers.

Therefore, you should use whatever spellings make sense within your local context.  That might mean, for your own convenience, that the spelling conventions that you use for your path segments are similar to those that you use when naming collections/tables in your data store.  Or perhaps not - you could equally decide that, because the audiences differ, so too should the spelling conventions.

```
GET /robots/:robotId/brain
GET /robots/:robotId/brains
GET /brains/:robotId
GET /ee4fcf74-d494-4f90-8964-9e4d65aa61ef
```

These are all *fine*.

Stefan Tilkov's 2014 talk: [REST: I don't Think it Means What You Think it Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM) may be helpful.

Comment: I've picked this answer as correct as it helped me to understand the issue most. I'll go with `GET /robots/:robotId/brain` because of the one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

For me, you should have only 1 endpoint `GET /robots/:robotId/brains`, you will get all your collection, but your frontend have to processing your data like he want

Comment: Do you suggest that by calling `GET /robots/:robotId/brains` we always receive an empty collection `[ ]` or a collection with 1 brain `[ {id: 1, robotId: '123', intellect: 100}]`?

Comment: You receive a collection with all the robot brains, create a new endpoint like GET /brains/:brainId if you want to get a specific brain

Answer (score 0):

If you have GET /robots/:robotId/brains this can still return a collection of size 1?

Comment: Yeah, it can but I'd like to get the `brain` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a rest end point which gives you the collection of all the brains of a robot. The uri should look like this :

`GET /robots/:robotId/brains`

Number of items the collection has should not matter.

If the rest end point is `GET /robots/:robotId/brain`, you are very much ignoring the fact that a robot might have multiple brains in the future and if very much possible if you database supports a one to many relationship.

To get 1 brain of a robot you can always keep scope for the below rest uri: `GET /robots/:robotId/brains/:brainId` Where brainId is the unique/primary key for a brain.